# Dynamic imported class variables in python

Tags: python, class

I have a setup similar to the following simplified code.

A config module containing variables:

```
## _cfg.py

cfg_var1 = 'old_value'
```

A module which has a class with variables:

```
## _io.py

import _cfg as cfg

class class1:

    class1_vars = {'var1':cfg.cfg_var1}
```

A script which the user actually interacts with:

```
## user.py

import _cfg as cfg
import _io as io

def main():
    cfg.cfg_var1 = 'new_value'

    print(io.class1_vars['var1'])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The trouble is that the io.class1_vars['var1'] in user.py does not reflect the modifications to the cfg.cfg_var1 variable. I understand why this is the case, but can't see a simple way to set this all up to achieve the desired outcome. The _cfg variables have to be modified (they get modified to reflect user input, etc.), and the _io class variables need to depend on the _cfg variables.

I thought of somehow re-declaring the class but I don't want to be in a position of having to know everywhere the _cfg variables are used when I modify them.

Can anyone think of a way to have the class variables look to the current _cfg variables when that class variable is actually used?

Comment: I've read your question 3 times and still can't get the point.

Comment: Just as an aside, this is fundamentally an unrecommended way of structuring your program, because this is just mutable global state with a thin layer around it.

Comment: Anyway, one way you could do this is that `cfg.cfg_var1` and `io.class1_vars["var1"]` should both point to the same mutable object, and then you mutate the object.

Comment: @kinetic_dust Are you trying to make the config file that user can change while program is running or what? I can't come up with any ideas about what you are trying to do.

Comment: Or, alternatively, your `class1` should do just that, look up the current variables when you ask the `cfg` for data. The simplest way is to implement methods that do that and then call those methods

Comment: @AbrahamTugalov Yes the config file will change while running, and the class variables that rely on them end up stale.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Looking up the current variables I guess is what I want to do here, but it's not exactly clear to me how I would implement it. Suggestions?

Comment: What I mean is that I don't know how to use a getter with a static class variable. Is this possible?

Comment: You could just make it an instance, but of course you can. You just set `class1.whatever = foo` in a `@staticmethod` or using a `@classmethod` you can use the `cls` argument